# What is the actual memory usage of unix domain sockets on Linux if only few bytes are transferred at a time

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, memory

Unix domain sockets under Linux have a default buffer size of 163840 bytes / 160kiB (32bit) or 212992 bytes / 208kiB (64bit), as is explained here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424380/what-values-may-linux-use-for-the-default-unix-socket-buffer-size.  These sizes can be adjusted with `setsockopt`, as explained here: [Maximum length of buffer in AF_UNIX socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052587/maximum-length-of-buffer-in-af-unix-socket)

However, assume a socket is created with default buffer size, but during its use there will be only small amounts of data transferred, such that the socket never fills up beyond, say, 1kiB of data.  There will be many exchanges like this during the life time of the socket, but at any moment there will only be a few bytes inside.

Will this socket then nevertheless truly occupy the 160kiB / 208kiB, or will only be, say, 2 pages of memory actually be used (one for each direction)?  I could imagine, for example, that the overcommit mechanism is also used for socket memory (which would to be effective also require that the kernel always re-locates the data in the socket rather than having a sliding-window through the buffer).

Background of the question: I would like to know whether it is worth to optimize socket memory usage with `setsockopt`, or whether the kernel's socket memory management will take care of this anyway.  In the latter case, manual configuration with `setsockopt` might even better be avoided to avoid problems due to misconfigurations...

Comment: Since Linux is open source, you can just [read the code directly](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/unix/af_unix.c?h=v5.17-rc8#n2139). You'll have to figure out what PAGE_ALIGN gives you, and add the overhead for the skb itself...